# Change password profile

Tags: profile, user-account

I'm running CiviCRM under Wordpress.

I want to create a donor area, where they can change their information.
But I can't find way to let them change their password.

Why is not possible to add a "password" field in profiles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't put this into a profile afaik. I use [Profile Builder](https://wordpress.org/plugins/profile-builder/) to create a separate front-end WP page. [Theme My Login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/) works ok too.

Answer (score 6):

CiviCRM does not maintain logins or credentials.  It instead opts to let the CMS (WordPress in your case) to manage it all.  CiviCRM can maintain the link between a user account on the CMS with a contact in CiviCRM though.

As Andrew West points out, you need to manage the password via WordPress.